# Stochastic process with limits of first and second moments finite

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This is a question about a strictly positive stochastic process in discrete-time.

> Suppose $(X_t)$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable stochastic process, defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, 
>   and assume $X_t > 0$ almost surely. Assume further $(X_t)$ satisfies for (integer) $n \in \lbrace-2,-1,1,2\rbrace$:
>   $$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K}^{n} | \mathcal{F}_t ]$$ exists and for 
>   each $n \in \lbrace-2,-1,1,2\rbrace$:
>   $$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K}^{n} | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$$.
>   (in words, the first and second moments and inverse moments have finite limits).

---

Is this true?
$$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] > 0$$
$$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ 1/(X_{t+K}) | \mathcal{F}_t ] > 0$$

---

Would it be true if I additionally assumed this: $$\sup_K \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K}^2 | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$$
$$\sup_K \mathbb{E}[ 1/(X_{t+K})^2 | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$$

Comment: My answer - no. With the additional assumption - yes.

Since the result is trivially true if $X_t$, for all $t$, is equal to a strictly positive constant, let us consider the case when $X_t$ is not constant. 

The proof uses Theorem 3.19 of Rudin (1976) ("If $a_n \leq b_n$, for all $n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$, provided both limits exist").

Comment: First, we have $0 < \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$ and 
$0 < \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$, for all $K \geq 1$.

Then Jensen's inequality implies, for all $t$, for all $K \geq 1$, that 
$\mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] > 1$.
Thus, by Theorem 3.19 of Rudin (1976), 
$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} ( \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] \, \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] ) > \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} 1$, 
or .......

Comment: .... or $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] \, \, \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] ) > 1$.

But since $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$ 
and $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} | \mathcal{F}_t ] < \infty$, the result must be true.

Comment: The proof shows that the additional assumption can be weakened to an L1 assumption, namely, 
$\sup_{K} \mathbb{E}[ X_{t+K} ] < \infty$ and $\sup_{K} \mathbb{E}[ 1/X_{t+K} ] < \infty$.